# Which the columns available on the TIGER geocoder

Tags: postgis, census, tiger

I have a local setup of the tiger geocoder and I want to extract as much information as possible from it.
Currently, from a query

```
SELECT g.rating, ST_X(geomout) As lon, ST_Y(geomout) As lat, (addy).* FROM geocode('75 State Street, Boston MA 02109', 1) As g;
```

I'm only getting this features:

```
rating |        lon        |       lat        | address | predirabbrev | streetname | streettypeabbrev | postdirabbrev | internal | location | stateabbrev |  zip  | parsed 
--------+-------------------+------------------+---------+--------------+------------+------------------+---------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------+--------
      0 | -71.0556722990239 | 42.3589914927049 |      75 |              | State      | St               |               |          | Boston   | MA          | 02109 | t
```

Which other information is available to extract? 
I'm looking for census track, building type, parcel number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tiger data doesn't include parcels.  It just has street centerlines and census tract.

For census tract that may be be turned off loading by default since I recall it taking some space.  If it's not, you should get an answer with a query like:

```
SELECT get_tract(ST_Point(-71.101375, 42.31376) ) As tract_name;
```

or

```
  SELECT g.rating, get_tract(geomout) As ctract, ST_X(geomout) As lon,    
 ST_Y(geomout) As lat, (addy).* 
     FROM geocode('75 State Street, Boston MA 02109', 1) As g;
```